# libgit2 - need help to understand how git_diff_foreach works

Tags: libgit2

I'm using libgit2 0.22.2, odb/refdb backed by mysql. I was testing git_diff_foreach function, but not sure how it works, please advise!

Below is my testing data and code, I put a blob 'README.md' into odb and commit, the content was 'commit' and later I put another blob with same name into odb and commit, this time the content was 'commit test'

I was trying to diff the 2 tree to print diff deltas in 3 callbacks (file, hunk, line). But only the file callback printed something

update:

i debugged into the foreach function, there's error in diff.h git_diff_file__resolve_zero_size function. after return statement error pops up:

Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'len' was corrupted.

code:

get diff:

```
int error;
git_object *commit;
git_commit *parent = NULL;
error = git_revparse_single(&commit, repo, "HEAD^{commit}");
error = git_commit_parent(&parent, (git_commit *)commit, 0);

git_tree *commit_tree = NULL, *parent_tree = NULL;
error = git_commit_tree(&commit_tree, (git_commit *)commit);
error = git_commit_tree(&parent_tree, parent);

git_diff *diff = NULL;
error = git_diff_tree_to_tree(&diff, repo, commit_tree, parent_tree, NULL);

git_mysql_tree_diff(mysql, repo, diff);

git_object_free(commit);
git_commit_free(parent);
git_tree_free(commit_tree);
git_tree_free(parent_tree);
git_diff_free(diff);
```

iterate diff:

```
int each_file_cb(const git_diff_delta *delta,float progress,void *payload)
{
    printf("new file:%s \n", delta->new_file.path);
    printf("old file:%s \n", delta->old_file.path);

    return 0;
}

int each_hunk_cb(
    const git_diff_delta *delta,
    const git_diff_hunk *hunk,
    void *payload)
{

    printf("hunk header:%s \n", hunk->header);

    return 0;
}

int each_line_cb(
    const git_diff_delta *delta,
    const git_diff_hunk *hunk,
    const git_diff_line *line,
    void *payload)
{
    printf("line content:%s \n", line->content);

    return 0;
}

int git_mysql_tree_diff(git_diff *diff){
    int error;

    error = git_diff_foreach(diff,
        each_file_cb,
        each_hunk_cb,
        each_line_cb,
        NULL);

    return error;
}
```

Data:

```
# oid,                                     type, size, data
'92168310a2a8e8d6577028d97931fd104965f6c5', '2', '37', 100644 README.md �����؊�J��B���f�N
'9f4ee02f459f6a28fa7a129fde6653d971429336', '1', '248', tree 92168310a2a8e8d6577028d97931fd104965f6c5 parent ad6aa3d0fcecefa5e9ea250a069da4d3be1f8e3d author Jerry Jin <jerry.yang.jin@gmail.com> 1430376253 +0800 committer Jerry Jin <jerry.yang.jin@gmail.com> 1430376253 +0800 encoding UTF-8 update readme
'ad6aa3d0fcecefa5e9ea250a069da4d3be1f8e3d', '1', '201', tree af0f65dba4ddecf5f4faf889cbd2852c341958c7 author Jerry Jin <jerry.yang.jin@gmail.com> 1430376223 +0800 committer Jerry Jin <jerry.yang.jin@gmail.com> 1430376223 +0800 encoding UTF-8 Initial Commit
'af0f65dba4ddecf5f4faf889cbd2852c341958c7', '2', '37', 100644 README.md ��vX"��}���lW�`@�#
'f8a612e3f687d88a984acaf41142ba85a3668d4e', '3', '11', commit test
'fcad765822a69c7de41bb1db186c57b160409923', '3', '6', commit
```

Output:

```
file progress:0.000000
```

Comment: There seem to be unnecessary references to mysql data types, but in any case, have you made sure that there *are* differences between your trees? You're not printing which file is being processed, so it's not clear that anything is happening.

Comment: Hi, Carlos, thanks for the reply, I debugged into the diff each function, there's error in diff.h GIT_INLINE(int) git_diff_file__resolve_zero_size function. after the return statement there was error:

Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'len' was corrupted.

Comment: there're memory issues in my code, that prevents the diff each to complete, will try to fix the memory issue and see the diff output

Answer (score 0):

after fixing memory issue, diff each printed below

```
new file:README.md
old file:README.md

hunk header:@@ -1 +1 @@

line content:commit testd
line content:
\ No newline at end of file

line content:commit;
line content:
\ No newline at end of file
```